# Object values and local values in arithmetic

Tags: java

So I was trying to perform a simple arithmetic on values within and object 'currentUser' in my one 'pricingAction' class.

The code should add the two volume values(doubles) and set the value of the variable to the sum of the two. In this example the volume_2, and volume_4 variable should be set to the sum of the two.

method 1:

```
if(filled4 == true){
    if(currentUser.getUtility_2().equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser.getUtility_4())){
        currentUser.setVolume_2(currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4());
        currentUser.setVolume_4(currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4());
    }
}
```

method 2:

```
if(filled3 == true){
    if(currentUser.getUtility_2().equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser.getUtility_3())){
        holder = 0;
        holder = currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_3();
        currentUser.setVolume_2(holder);
        currentUser.setVolume_3(holder);
    }
}
```

Method 2 returns the value expected and Method 1 appears to be tossing in a duplicate of the value it is setting to.

My question is why does Method 1 do this? I can only assume it is just tacking on the extra sum to the current value but the setter method is a generic `this.x = x;`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What are the values? The code makes little sense out of context.

Comment: Further more keep in mind that in method1 you are setting a value in setVolume_2 in the first arithmetic. In the next arithmetic the value of getVolume_2 is then the updated one from the first arithmetic. Is it possible getVolume_4 is 0 and thus it seems like the value is duplicated?

Comment: Although what it sounds like what you're not realising is that in your first method, your second line of code uses the value of volume 2 that you have *just increased*.

Comment: What type does getVolume_2() return?

Comment: code was updated to reflect a brief synopsis of what I was expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the code a little so it's easier to read:

```
foo.setX(foo.getX() + foo.getY());
foo.setY(foo.getX() + foo.getY());
```

Now suppose we start with `foo.X = 10`, `foo.Y = 20`.

The first statement will initially compute `foo.X + foo.Y` - which is 10+20, or 30.
It then sets that (30) as a *new* value for `foo.X`.

The second statement will initially compute `foo.X + foo.Y`, which is now 30+20, or 50. Note that this is using the new value of `foo.X`. It then sets 50 as a *new* value for `foo.Y`.

If you want to set the same value for both properties, you should compute that value *once*, to avoid the change to the value of the first property from affecting the computation. However, it's clearer to declare the local variable for that value as locally as you can:

```
double result = foo.getX() + foo.getY();
foo.setX(result);
foo.setY(result);
```

That's not only correct, but it's also easier to understand *and* more efficient. Bonus!

Comment: Oh wow, thanks I've been messing with this at work for the last hour and somehow missed that. I guess was just trying to over complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set the value of volume2 before using its new value to set volume4.

```
currentUser.setVolume_2(currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4());
// volume2 now set with new value
// which you are about to use below
currentUser.setVolume_4(currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is performing two additions (and I suspect you wanted one) -

```
if(currentUser.getUtility_2().equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser.getUtility_4())){
  // Changes volume 2
  currentUser.setVolume_2(currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4());
  currentUser.setVolume_4(currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4());
}
```

Should probably be

```
if(currentUser.getUtility_2().equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser.getUtility_4())){
  int newVolume = currentUser.getVolume_2() + currentUser.getVolume_4();
  currentUser.setVolume_2(newVolume);
  currentUser.setVolume_4(newVolume);
}
```